# Record current tab in chrome using chrome extension and getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia, screen-recording

I am trying to make a Chrome extension to record user activity in the current tab.

I found out that I can use [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) on the front, and [chrome.desktopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) in my background script.

However, when I try to use chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['tab'], onApproved), I get prompted for the tab I want to share. However, I would like to skip this step and share my current tab without the prompt.

I know that this can be done, because in the [Screencastify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn/related?hl=en) Chrome extension, you can do that. The first option is to record the current tab and no popups are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at chrome.tabCapture API?  It can be used inside of an extension, and unlike the chrome.desktopCapture API can be called programmatically without a prompt.  The limitation is that the chrome.tabCapture API can only be used within an extension, and cannot be used within a Chrome packaged app (tested and verified in my own attempts at using the "tabCapture" permission in a custom packaged app).  So, if you are just writing an extension, the chrome.tabCapture API might be your best option.